# When I write "npm start" terminal is showing bindings error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

this is the error i get after running `npm start`

```
> tictactoe@0.1.0 start
> parcel index.html

D:\courses\TicTacToe\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126
  err = new Error(
        ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → D:\courses\TicTacToe\node_modules\deasync\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\deasync.node
    at bindings (D:\courses\TicTacToe\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\courses\\TicTacToe\node_modules\deasync\index.js:30:31)
    at Module._compile (D:\courses\TicTacToe\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)   
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (D:\courses\TicTacToe\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\courses\TicTacToe\node_modules\parcel\src\utils\syncPromise.js:1:79)       
    at Module._compile (D:\courses\TicTacToe\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30) {
```

I tried installed npm again, but same error.

Comment: Did you run "npm install"?

Comment: yes i did run npm install, but same error